# Finagle server dont ready after start

Tags: java, scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I have a Finagle server which apperently there´s no way to know when is rerally up.

Having this code

```
esbMockServer = Some(defaultServer
        .serve(s"localhost:$esbPort", esbService))
      println(s"Running Finagle Regular Esb Mock Server in port $esbPort.......")
      Await.ready(esbMockServer.get,10 second)
```

Always throw a timeout exception in the Await, but it´s up and running properly since second 1.

Any idea what´s wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Await.ready` does not do what you seem to think it does. It's basically the same as `Await.result`, except that it returns the `Awaitable` object itself rather than the result.

The bottom line is, `Await.ready` will return *after* the `Server` is *stopped* (`.close` is called on it), not when it is "ready" ... the latter should be the case, pretty much, right away, you don't need to wait for it.

Typically, you'll want to put `Await.ready(server)` at the end of your `main` function to block the main thread forever, until the server exits.

Comment: Sorry but "the latter should be the case, pretty much, right away, you don't need to wait for it." It´s not clear, what do you mean?. If I dont put a Thread.sleep(5000) then the request crash since the server is not yet ready. Also I´m using the same thread to run the server and run my tests.

Comment: What "request crash"?

Comment: If I start the server then I make a request to that server, without wait N time I receive an error since the request fail. If I put a Thread.sleep of 5 seconds normally the request works. But obviously is not very deterministic this mechanism.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Why start the server, and send requests to it right away? This seems like some sort of an anti-pattern. You should not be using the same code for testing that you use in production. 
Deploy the server first. Wait for health-check to succeed. Then use a separate job to send  requests to it for testing.

Comment: Of course we do that, but finagle server is really slow the first time and some of my test fails since I need to do a warm up first.

Comment: So, do a warm up ... Not sure, what it has to do with the original question. Make health check no succeed until warm up is completed.

Comment: The question was do the warm up after we know the server is up and running.

Comment: That's' not a a question :)

Comment: Ok, simple, many http servers as Vertx or Akka http server has a future to know when the port of the server is ready to receive any request. Do or not have Finagle a similar mechanism. And, as you already responses me it don’t

Comment: Yes, not that I know of. What I have been trying to say here is that I don't really see any use for such mechanism, if it did exist.